# How to do some operations on a Spark dataset no affecting the data structure?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, duplicates, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark datasets API to remove near duplicates. What I'm trying to do is group the duplicated rows in order to leave only one row from each group but with a column specifying the number of rows which have been collapsed into this row.

Consider the following example. I have the following data where the last field specifies the rows collapsed into that row:

- A,B,C,5
- A,D,G,1

At this point, I would like to group the data by the first field, keep the rest of fields of the row with most rows collapsed into it and add the number of rows collapsed into the second one to the first one. So the result would be:

- A,B,C,6

I've already implemented it and the problem is about the format of the resulting data.

Here is my code:

```
val sameTitleArticlesCollapsed = articlesCollapsed.groupByKey(_.TITLE).reduceGroups((a,b) => if(a.TIMES_COLLAPSED > b.TIMES_COLLAPSED) a.copy(TIMES_COLLAPSED = a.TIMES_COLLAPSED + b.TIMES_COLLAPSED) else b.copy(TIMES_COLLAPSED = a.TIMES_COLLAPSED + b.TIMES_COLLAPSED)).toDF("key", "data")
```

If I execute `printSchema` on `sameTitleArticlesCollapsed`, the output is:

```
root
|-- key: string (nullable = true)
|-- data: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- CODE: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- TITLE: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- NAUTHORS: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- AUTHORS: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- TIMES_COLLAPSED: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
```

I don't care about the `key` column and what I would like is to extract the data inside the `data` column to keep it in the same format as before applying the `groupByKey - reduceGroups`.

```
root
 |-- CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TITLE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NAUTHORS: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AUTHORS: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TIMES_COLLAPSED: long (nullable = false)
```

How could I do that? Is there any better way to do this process?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add a map at the end like shown below to retain the original schema

```
val sameTitleArticlesCollapsed = articlesCollapsed.groupByKey(_.title).reduceGroups((a,b) => if(a.times_collapsed > b.times_collapsed) a.copy(times_collapsed = a.times_collapsed + b.times_collapsed) else b.copy(times_collapsed = a.times_collapsed + b.times_collapsed))

val result = sameTitleArticlesCollapsed.map({case (_,value) => value}).toDF

result.printSchema
root
 |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nauthors: string (nullable = true)
 |-- authors: string (nullable = true)
 |-- times_collapsed: long (nullable = true)
```